# Eloquent Relationships: user hasmany posts has many comments

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using laravel and i am trying to create my database with `Users`, this user will have many `comments` and many `posts`, the catch is that the post also need to have many comments that all will belong to a post. And that the comments from the user will belong to a post.

Maybe im thinking about it in the wrong way, but cant figure it out.

Help is apriciated

[image: Image representing what i want]

Comment: um, what help do you require? as far as i can tell, its totally valid and doable in laravel.

Comment: Does a User actually have comments? Maybe take a look at HasManyThrough (User "hasMany" Comments "Through" Post)

Comment: You can look at this website to get a better understanding https://webdevtrainee.com/laravel-9-eloquent-relationships/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comment can `belongTo` both a `Post` and a `Comment`.  So, a solution could look something like this:

## Relationships

#### User

- `hasMany` Post
- `hasMany` Comment

#### Post

- `belongsTo` User
- `hasMany` Comment

#### Comment

- `belongTo` User
- `belongsTo` Post

## Models

| User |
| --- |
| id |

| Post |
| --- |
| id |
| user_id |

| Comment |
| --- |
| id |
| user_id |
| post_id |